# Do we call all types of progress indicators a loader?

Tags: ux-designer, progress-bar, loading, indicator

Do we call all types of progress indicators a loader.

Comment: Would you call all types of loaders a progress indicator?

Comment: I agree that "progress indicator" is better, since "loading" has implications about the task being performed.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to the site.

I understand your question to simply be about terminology. If that's correct, then "no" - in our company (some) people call this a "busy indicator".